# Roll-your-own mysql-server (.deb) files and MySQL root password

Tags: server, package-management, mysql

I know I can make my own .deb files of an installation. However, during a normal mysql-server install, the root password gets asked for and we need to do a 1-click rollout without ANY interaction.
It needs to install AND set the root password.

Can I "roll-my-own" mysql-server.deb **AND** have the package that I roll set the root password?

Articles I am reviewing are:

> http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/336
>   http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/20

For now, I just need to know if this is possible.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained well on http://www.rndguy.ca/2010/02/24/fully-automated-ubuntu-server-setups-using-preseed/ you don't need to create your own packages of mysql, as it uses debconf to ask the root password question. The answers to these questions can be preseeded as part of a scripted installation process.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/19367/scripted-install-of-mysql-on-ubuntu has a similar method of doing it with debconf

Comment: Options! We love options.  
Thank you. You Rock!

Comment: While reviewing this process today, I notice that the preseed works IF the mysql-server has already been installed and removed. Unless I am missing somthing at http://www.rndguy.ca/2010/02/24/fully-automated-ubuntu-server-setups-using-preseed/

Comment: While reviewing this process today, I notice that the preseed works IF the mysql-server has already been installed and/or  removed?  Unless I am missing somthing at http://www.rndguy.ca/2010/02/24/fully-automated-ubuntu-server-setups-using-preseed/  Even he has sudo apt-get install going there. How can I completely clean the debconf db from any/all mysql-server entries?

Comment: dis-regard my last comment, I am an idiot. 'sudo apt-get purge mysql*' does the job.